# Best Data structure to store subnets for matching Ip address with subnet

Tags: java, networking, data-structures, network-programming, subnet

I have a list of records with below fields in each record.

```
<Network address of subnet, subnet mask, Object>.
```

For every incoming packet i have to read the client address, AND it with each subnet mask to figure out which subnet (from my list) it belongs to and return corresponding object.

Currently I am using HashMap with network address as a key to store records. But the problem is, if an Ip address belongs to more than one subnet in the table, then I have to choose the one which has largest CIDR prefix (smallest subnetwork) and I can not go with any other subnet.

For example, I have below two records

```
<128.30.20.0, 255.255.255.0, Object-1>
<128.30.0.0, 255.255.0.0, Object-2>
```

Then an Ip address "128.30.20.1" should always choose first record because it is a smaller network than the second one. Hashmap doesn't guarantee that records will be in correct order.
My approach is to keep these records in such a way that they will always be in such order that smaller networks are always at the beginning.

This list of records will be passed to some other application wherein they just iterate through the list to find out the match starting from 0 position. (they just don't want extra processing at their end.)

Could anyone please suggest some data structure in java to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When u say list, am assuming u mean map. How about treemap? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html
Note that a custom comparstor would be used to setyle on the iteration order that is desired.

Comment: Yes.. I chose TreeMap with custom comparator. Thanks.